# How can I check check for matching values in a second dataframe, then return a value from a column in the second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. One contains a list of the most recent meeting for each customer. The second is a list of statuses that each customer has been recorded with, and their start date and end date.

I want to look up a customer and meeting date, and find out what status they were at when the meeting occurred.

What I *think* this will involve is creating a new column in my meeting dataframe that checks the rows of the statuses dataframe for a matching customer ID, then checks if the date from the first dataframe is between two dates in the second. If it is, the calculated column will take its value from the second dataframe's status column.

My dataframes are:

**meeting**

```
| CustomerID | MeetingDate |
|------------|-------------|
| 70704      | 2019-07-23  |
| 70916      | 2019-09-04  |
| 72712      | 2019-04-16  |
```

**statuses**

```
| CustomerID | Status | StartDate  | EndDate    |
|------------|--------|------------|------------|
| 70704      | First  | 2019-04-01 | 2019-06-30 |
| 70704      | Second | 2019-07-01 | 2019-08-25 |
| 70916      | First  | 2019-09-01 | 2019-10-13 |
| 72712      | First  | 2019-03-15 | 2019-05-02 |
```

So, I think I want to take meeting.CustomerID and find a match in statuses.CustomerID. I then want to check if meeting.MeetingDate is between statuses.StartDate and statuses.EndDate. If it is, I want to return statuses.Status from the matching row, if not, ignore that row and move to the next to see if that matches the criteria and return the Status as described.

The final result should look like:

```
| CustomerID | MeetingDate | Status |
|------------|-------------|--------|
| 70704      | 2019-07-23  | Second |
| 70916      | 2019-09-04  | First  |
| 72712      | 2019-04-16  | First  |
```

I'm certain there must be a neater and more streamlined way to do this than what I've suggested, but I'm still learning the ins and outs of python and pandas and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to wrangle something that works for me:

```
df = statuses.merge(meetings, on='CustomerID')
df = df[(df['MeetingDate'] >= df['StartDate']) & (df['MeetingDate'] <= df['EndDate'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Gives:

```
| CustomerID | Status | StartDate  | EndDate    | MeetingDate |
|------------|--------|------------|------------|-------------|
| 70704      | Second | 2019-01-21 | 2019-07-28 | 2019-07-23  |
| 70916      | First  | 2019-09-04 | 2019-10-21 | 2019-09-04  |
| 72712      | First  | 2019-03-19 | 2019-04-17 | 2019-04-16  |
```

And I can just drop the now unneeded columns.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. If the columns are not sorted by `CustomerID` or `Status`, this can be easily done. This is assuming your dates are already a `datetime` type. Here, `df2` refers to the dataframe whose columns are `CustomerID`, `Status`, `StartDate`, and `EndDate`.

```
import numpy as np

df2 = df2[::-1]
row_arr = np.unique(df2.CustomerID, return_index = True)[1]

df2 = df2.iloc[row_arr, :].drop(['StartDate', 'EndDate'], axis = 1)
final = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = 'CustomerID')
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the data is sorted? I've tried the example given but it's mismatching and returning a later status than when the meeting was. 

For example, customer 70704 had their meeting on 2019-07-23. The code is matching them to status 3, but the start date of status 3 was 2019-08-26. I need it to match to status 2, because the meeting date falls after that status started, but before it ended.

Comment: I managed to figure out a bit of a messy solution, but it works. Thanks for the pointers!